# Somehow my singleton properties are getting released

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nszombie

I have a singleton object called `PoolManager` that loads and saves some data in a plist.  Throughout my program when something needs to know about my pool, it asks the `[PoolManager sharedPoolManager]` for it's properties.  I have a single view that's responsible for setting these properties and all others just read from it.  It was all working fine, and then for no reason I can tell, it started crashing.  I set `NSZombieEnabled = YES` and can see that when I access one of the two `NSString` properties, they appear to have been released.  The debugger message is: `*** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5a336d0`

I tried going back to a previous snapshot where everything worked and it still does this.  I even used TimeMachine to go back to the project from yesterday and it does it too.  I'm baffled.

Here is the singleton object code...  It's the `surface` and `shape` strings that are apparently zombies.  Sorry for all the `NSLogs`

---

```
//  MyPoolSingleton.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define kFileName @"data.plist"

@interface PoolManager : NSObject {
    float   volume;
    float length;
    float width;
    float depth;    
    NSString *surface;
    NSString *shape;
    BOOL isMetric;
    int fcTarget;
    int cyaTarget;
    int taTarget;
    int chTarget;
    int saltTarget;
}

@property float volume;
@property float length;
@property float width;
@property float depth;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *surface;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *shape;
@property BOOL isMetric;
@property int fcTarget;
@property int cyaTarget;
@property int taTarget;
@property int chTarget;
@property int saltTarget;

+ (PoolManager*)sharedPoolManager;
- (void)retrieveState;
- (void)saveState;
- (NSString*)dataFilePath;

@end
```

---

```
//  MyPoolSingleton.m

#import "PoolManager.h"

@implementation PoolManager

@synthesize volume;
@synthesize length;
@synthesize width;
@synthesize depth;
@synthesize surface;
@synthesize shape;
@synthesize isMetric;
@synthesize fcTarget;
@synthesize cyaTarget;
@synthesize taTarget;
@synthesize chTarget;
@synthesize saltTarget;

static PoolManager* _sharedPoolManager = nil;

+ (PoolManager*)sharedPoolManager {
    @synchronized([PoolManager class])
    {
        if (!_sharedPoolManager)
            [[self alloc] init];
        return _sharedPoolManager;
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (id)alloc {
    @synchronized([PoolManager class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedPoolManager == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedPoolManager = [super alloc];
        return _sharedPoolManager;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)retrieveState {
    NSLog(@"--retrieveState");
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"    fileExistsAtPath: reading array from plist");
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        volume = [[array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: volume = %1.1f", volume);
        length = [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: length = %1.1f", length);
        width = [[array objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: width = %1.1f", width);
        depth = [[array objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: depth = %1.1f", depth);
        self.surface = [array objectAtIndex:4];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: surface = %@", surface);
        self.shape = [array objectAtIndex:5];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: shape = %@", shape);
        isMetric = [[array objectAtIndex:6] boolValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: isMetric = %d", isMetric);
        fcTarget = [[array objectAtIndex:7] intValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: fcTarget = %d", fcTarget);
        cyaTarget = [[array objectAtIndex:8] intValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: cyaTarget = %d", cyaTarget);
        taTarget = [[array objectAtIndex:9] intValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: taTarget = %d", taTarget);
        chTarget = [[array objectAtIndex:10] intValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: chTarget = %d", chTarget);
        saltTarget = [[array objectAtIndex:11] intValue];
            NSLog(@"      reading array: saltTarget = %d", saltTarget);
        [array release];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"    !fileExistsAtPath: intitializing values to nil/zero");
        volume = 0.0;
        length = 0.0;
        width = 0.0;
        depth = 0.0;
        surface = @"";
        shape = @"";
        isMetric = NO;
        fcTarget = 0.0;
        cyaTarget = 0.0;
        taTarget = 0.0;
        chTarget = 0.0;
        saltTarget = 0.0;
    }
}

- (void)saveState {
    NSLog(@"--saveState");
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"      building array: volume = %1.1f", volume);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:volume]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: length = %1.1f", length);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:length]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: width = %1.1f", width);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:width]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: depth = %1.1f", depth);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:depth]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: surface = %@", surface);
    [array addObject:surface];
        NSLog(@"      building array: shape = %@", shape);
    [array addObject:shape];
        NSLog(@"      building array: isMetric = %d", isMetric);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isMetric]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: fcTarget = %d", fcTarget);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fcTarget]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: cyaTarget = %d", cyaTarget);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cyaTarget]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: taTarget = %d", taTarget);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:taTarget]];
            NSLog(@"      building array: chTarget = %d", chTarget);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:chTarget]];
        NSLog(@"      building array: saltTarget = %d", saltTarget);
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:saltTarget]];

    [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [array release];
}    

- (NSString*)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFileName];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [shape release], shape = nil;
    [surface release], surface = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Just to make your code shorter, you can do
@synthesize var1, var2, var2;

instead of having a separate line for each of them.

Comment: Thanks, I've started to go back and clean things like that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objectAtIndex:` gives an autoreleased object. You should either retain it, or use the property accessor `self.surface = ...` and `self.shape = ...`  when setting those.

Comment: Switching to `self.surface` and `self.shape` did the trick.  Thanks!  I still don't understand how it ran fine since last night and then decided to start crashing.  Oh well.  BTW, is there a list of autoreleased objects, or methods that return autoreleased objects for reference?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer the following pattern for singletons:

```
+ (id) sharedPoolManager
{
    static id sharedPoolManager = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (sharedPoolManager == nil) {
             sharedPoolManager = [self new];
        }
    }
    return sharedPoolManager;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
         // Initialize ... nothing special here ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

(Note that `self` in a class method is equivalent to `[SomeClass class]`)

The above is more concise and I prefer to keep any singleton code outside of `init` and `alloc` since I can then also create multiple instances if needed. For example in unit tests.

Personally I don't think you have to protect the programmer from creating multiple instances. The contract is clear: `sharedPoolManager` returns a singleton instance. If that is what you want/need then use that. Otherwise create instances the usual way.

Comment: I like the way this looks better than what I have, but what about `- (id)alloc`?

I thought about just making an instance and passing it around, but that seemed like more work.  It's easy to instantiate something and assign it's properties to pass something in, but the only way I've figured out how to go the other way is to use delegation.

Comment: You really don't need the `alloc` for a singleton. The default implementation will do fine. Unless I misunderstand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ohhh. Yes, `[Foo new]` is a shortcut for ``[[Foo alloc] init]`. Nobody seems to use it anymore except me, but it is perfectly legal. Part of `NSObject`. See docs :-)